# How can I split two datetime into one range?

Tags: php, datetime

I would like to know how I can a two `datetime` from MySQL split into one range. I'm creating event system where I need from users input set a range.

**Input:**

```
date from: 2015-03-05
date to: 2015-03-07
```

I want from this two variables get this:

**Output:**

```
Mar 5–7, 2015
```

If months and year are different

```
Diff. month: Mar 31 – Apr 2, 2015
Diff. year: Dec 31 2014 – Jan 2, 2015
```

Comment: That's open to a lot of interpretations, what should happen when the months or years differ?

Comment: I added two interpretations what can happen in my case.

Comment: Okay, and where are you stuck exactly, what do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution. you can reduce some code although.

```
<?php 
    $dateFrom ="2014-03-05";
    $dateTo   ="2015-04-07";

    $part1= '';
    $part2= '';

    if(date('M',strtotime($dateFrom)) == date('M' ,strtotime($dateTo))){
        $part1= date('M',strtotime($dateFrom)).' '.date('j',strtotime($dateFrom));
        $part2= date('j',strtotime($dateTo));
    } else {
        $part1= date('M',strtotime($dateFrom)).' '.date('j',strtotime($dateFrom));
        $part2= date('M',strtotime($dateTo)).' '.date('j',strtotime($dateFrom));
    }
    $stringFinal = $part1.' - '.$part2.', ';

    if(date('Y',strtotime($dateFrom)) == date('Y' ,strtotime($dateTo))){
        $stringFinal = $part1.' - '.$part2.', '.' '.date('Y',strtotime($dateFrom));

    } else {
        $stringFinal = $part1.' '.date('Y',strtotime($dateFrom)).' - '.$part2.', '.' '.date('Y',strtotime($dateTo));
    }

    echo $stringFinal;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A rather more elegant solution is possible using the [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime) classes and by moving everything into a function. Something like:-

```
/**
 * @param string $from
 * @param string $to
 * @return string
 */
function dateDiffString($from, $to)
{
    $fromDate = new \DateTime($from);
    $toDate = new \DateTime($to);
    if($fromDate->format('Y') !== $toDate->format('Y')){
        return $fromDate->format('M d Y') . " - " . $toDate->format('M d Y');
    }
    if($fromDate->format('m') !== $toDate->format('m')){
        return $fromDate->format('M d') . ' - ' . $toDate->format('M d, Y');
    }
    return $fromDate->format('M d') . ' - ' . $toDate->format('d, Y');
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://3v4l.org/bS5ls) using your example inputs.